# Meaning of "PDOStatement extends \PDOStatement" in Doctrine source code : namespace or class?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, namespaces

Line 28 of my `vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php`
is as follows :

```
class PDOStatement extends \PDOStatement implements Statement
```

I am not sure how this should be read. In the documentation at php.net I read a lot about `PDOStatement`, but nothing about `\PDOStatement`.
Does `\PDOStatement` designate a namespace or a class ? The blackslash suggests a namespace, but the `extends` keyword demands a class. What is the point of the backslash here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash refers to the global namespace so \PDOStatement refers to the one referenced by php.net. The "PDOStatement" at the start of the line is a new class defined under the current namespace, I presume you have something like `namespace MyNamespace;` at the top of this file. This new class will inherit all the methods of the global class.

Comment: There is a `namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;` at the top of the file indeed. So `\PDOStatement` is shorthand here for `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement` ?

Comment: Not quite, PDOStatement here is shorthand for `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement`. \PDOStatement is the global class defined by the PDO extension. The backslash is just a way of referencing global classes when inside a namespace. Normally you wouldn't see this if not in a namespaced file.

Comment: I think I see now : the backslash in `\PDOStatement` is there to tell the system the class is from the global namespace and from nowhere else